# How does Realm resolve conflicts in Lists?

Tags: realm

How is Realm Mobile Database able to resolve conflicts from multiple users writing to the same List at the same time?

It doesn't seem to be a simple last write wins situation. For example in List [a, b, c, d], user1 can swap a and b [b, a, c, d] and user2 can swap c and d [a, b, d, c]. Once synced they both have the combined changes [b, a, d, c].

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships Don't Lists in realm maintain sort order? If so, swap means remove b at index 1 and insert b at index 0.

Comment: gah, it does say `List properties are guaranteed to preserve their order of insertion.` never mind me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conflicts are generally always resolved such that it would appear that the corresponding operations were carried out locally in the real-time order in which they actually happened on different devices.

Inserts are ordered such that if two devices are appending elements to the list, the elements will end up in the order in which they were appended.

Element swap operations are a little more difficult to visualize, but the same principle applies. If you swap have the list `[a, b, c]` and each device independently does `swap(0, 1)` at `t=0` and `swap(1, 2)` at `t=1`, respectively, the result will be as if the operations `swap(0, 1)` and then `swap(0, 2)` had been run on each device, yielding `[c, a, b]`. Notice how the second swap has been transformed to take the first into account, maintaining list element identity.

The easiest way to reason about conflict resolution is that it always resolves conflicts such that it appears the operations had happened locally. We would like to improve our documentation around this behavior, but the challenge is that there are many combinations of operations. If you have any suggestions regarding which kind of information in the documentation would have answered your question, please do not hesitate to send us further feedback.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't phrase my question well enough. Your answer sounds like what I was explaining as the end result in my question. Internally, how are actions carried out "such that it would appear that the corresponding operations were carried out locally in the real-time order"? Does the array contain an internal timestamp and when an action is performed a message is stored with an objectId, timestamp and payload of the action to perform or something like that? The message can then go through the sync api?

Comment: The algorithm is called Operational Transformation, and is well described in the literature. This algorithm was chosen for Realm Mobile Platform for a variety of reasons, one of them the fact that it doesn't bloat the database by having to store timestamps for each list element, but instead we are using timestamps in the operation log. Note that the timestamp is only used to resolve a limited class of conflicts, and only in order to give the appearance of changes having happened in "natural" order.